# Como buscar informações de uma tabela pelo id e mandar para para uma outra parte na mesma página?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5, bootstrap-4

eu estou aprendendo a programar a pouco tempo e estou criando meu primeiro sistema, que é um sistema de boletins escolares, onde tenho uma aba chamada **alunos** que contém uma tabela gerada através de um cadastro, cada item dessa tabela tem um ícone de edição que redireciona o usuário para um formulário onde ele registra a nota do respectivo aluno. Eu preciso que quando o usuário clicar no ícone e ele for redirecionado para o formulário as notas registradas devem ser do aluno selecionado. E a página é toda feita com bootstrap

Comment: se possível coloque seu cod, print screens e ou até modelagem do banco

Comment: Olá Pedro. É necessário que você estude um pouco sobre métodos HTTP como GET e POST. No seu caso especificamente você poderia usar o GET para enviar o código do aluno para outra página. No seu ícone de edição deve conter um link que vai pra página de visualização das notas e no link incluir o código do aluno que você quer visualizar. Já na página de notas você captura esse valor para pesquisar com ele no seu banco de dados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenta criar esse ícone do item como link, e no link põe pra chamar a pagina especifica e atribui um parâmetro como por exemplo

```
<a href="editar-alunos.php?id=1">Editar</a>
```

no php você faz a consulta vindo do parametro:

```
$id = $_GET['id']; //Recebe o parâmetro passado pela sua url
```

e faz a consulta no banco de dados

```
$alunos = ("SELECT * FROM alunos WHERE id = '$id'");
```

Crie um formulário com os campos onde você ira informar os valores do aluno para possíveis alteração por exemplo:

```
<input type="text" name="nome" value="<?php echo $row['nome'] ?>"> //em Value você imprime a informação do aluno de acordo com a sua necessidade.
```

depois é só aplicar a ação de alteração.

Comment: Isso mesmo segue esse exemplo que vai da certo.

Comment: Na verdade preciso que o ícone redirecione pra o formulário onde registro as notas:

Comment: faz uma chamada de uma pagina por este ícone exemplo: <a href="pagina-do-form.php?id=id-do-aluno">Icone-aqui</a>

na pagina-do-form.php cria uma variavel para receber o parametro via get por exemplo: $id = $_GET['id']; que foi o parametro passado pelo icone id=id-do-aluno.

na variável que recebe o valor você pode utilizar no seu formulário para possíveis alterações. Caso de duvida publica seu codigo para eu te ajudar.

Comment: Consegui aqui, deu certo.Obg!